# How do I append an existing html element to another element?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I want to append multiple copies of div with id **hello** into the div with id **container**. How do I do this using javascript?

```html
<div id="container">

</div>

<div id="hello">
   <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: id should be unique in a page

Comment: As @SagarV said, `id` is supposed to be having a unique value in a page. I would recommend you use `class` for this.

Comment: Hey it would be easier to do that with jquery using  by storing you div with id="hello " inside $('#mydiv').append('html content')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cloneNode` and `appendChild`.

Since `id`s should be unique in a document, I switched things to use a class `hello` instead.

```js
function makeCopy() {
  const target = document.getElementById("container");
  const source = document.querySelector(".hello");
  const clone = source.cloneNode(true);
  target.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```css
.hello {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px dotted orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  This is the container.
</div>

<button onclick="makeCopy()">Add a clone of hello above</button>


<div class="hello">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

check this out, it will solve your problem, BUT use a class for the tag not an ID. IDs are unique, a class is for multiple elements.

you can call class in CSS like this

```
.className {
  /*CODE*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use append() method:

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
   $('#container').append( $('#hello') ); 
});
```